# Como limpiar un String de caracteres de programacion

Tags: java, string

En mi app el usuario escribe información atreves de un EditText y quiero que al obtener ese dato se eliminen caracteres como: `` "!$#%&/(=?'\¡¿¨´+*{[^`}]`_.,;:°|¬ ``

el String lo Obtengo con

```
String ETUserinfoObtained = ETInfo.getText().toString();
```

y trato de remplazar los caracteres con

```
ETUserinfoObtained.replaceAll("Aqui deberian de estar los caracteres que quiero eliminar", "");
```

Comment: y cual seria el problema?

Comment: que no se como poner los caracteres que quiero eliminar en el replaceAll("Aqui","");

Comment: leiste la documentacion sobre lo que hace esa funcion?

Comment: si pero no logre encontrar el como ponerlo ya que al poner [ me da error

Comment: Tengo esto String UserInfoClean = UserInfoObtained.replaceAll("<", ""); la cosa es que no se como hacer para que quite todos los demas caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String#replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) toma una expresión regular (regex). Te recomiendo buscar información online sobre la sintaxis de éstas si vas a usarlas (hay algunos links en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).
De lo contrario, te diría que te olvides de esto y vayas con métodos clásicos, como usar un bucle para ir reemplazando cada uno de los caracteres que quieras... vamos, que no tiene nada de malo!

Podrías eliminar todo *lo que NO sea* una letra o espacio, para eso lee [la respuesta de Roger the Developer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/403742/193460).

O podrías eliminar ***exactamente*** los símbolos que mencionaste en la pregunta:

```
tuString.replaceAll( "[\"!$#%&/(=?'\\\\¡¿¨´+*{\\[^`}\\]`_.,;:°|¬]+", "")
```

- Los corchetes que engloban a esta expresión significan "*que coincida con alguno de estos caracteres*". El `+` del final hace que también coincida con otros caracteres que estén a continuación.
- Los que están escapados con una `\` son caracteres especiales que tendrían un significado diferente en el regex si no se escaparan.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba a utilizar un regex o expresión regular,
el siguiente regex elimina del string todo carácter especial.

```java
String clean = ETUserinfoObtained.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]", "");
```

Comment: No me funciono me dio error, lo necesito para java

Comment: De acuerdo, funciono muchas gracias bro.